# Ubuntu 17 - 2880x1800 resolution

Tags: display-resolution, dpi

I looked for a solution online. I would like to use the full retina resolution with Ubuntu. As you can imagine, text are too small. I resized them using gnome tweak tool. However, scaling at 1.5 is still not enough, and instead, if I set the resize at 2.0 the text started to be too big and went out of the windows: they are too big to be shown in the current window are not visible (see image below).
Is there any solution to this issue apart from setting a lower resolution? Any other DE? [image]

Comment: How about 1.75?

Comment: Anything more than 1.5 produces the effect shown in the picture. Anyway, not all the applications show the problem. I can still try to use 2.0. But, is there any way to resize the close/minimize icons of the windows?